# More/less code in footer.php Problem with elementor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code for the footer.php

When I add it more / less works but when I try to edit pages with Elementor or Elementor it doesn't work.

I get stuck in the Elementor loading screen as soon as I have the code in the footer.php.

If I remove the code from footer.php, Elementor works again.

What can I do to make both work at the same time?

in snippert it doesn't work but on my side it does hmm..

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> 
    <script>
    function AddReadMore() {
        //This limit you can set after how much characters you want to show Read More.
        var carLmt = 140;
        // Text to show when text is collapsed
        var readMoreTxt = "... <span>More</span>";
        // Text to show when text is expanded
        var readLessTxt = " <span class='cless'>Less</span>";


        //Traverse all selectors with this class and manupulate HTML part to show Read More
        $(".addReadMore").each(function() {
            if ($(this).find(".firstSec").length)
                return;

            var allstr = $(this).text();
            if (allstr.length > carLmt) {
                var firstSet = allstr.substring(0, carLmt);
                var secdHalf = allstr.substring(carLmt, allstr.length);
                var strtoadd = firstSet + "<span class='SecSec'>" + secdHalf + "</span><span class='readMore'  title='Click to Show More'>" + readMoreTxt + "</span><span class='readLess' title='Click to Show Less'>" + readLessTxt + "</span>";
                $(this).html(strtoadd);
            }

        });
        //Read More and Read Less Click Event binding
        $(document).on("click", ".readMore,.readLess", function() {
            $(this).closest(".addReadMore").toggleClass("showlesscontent showmorecontent");
        });
    }
    $(function() {
        //Calling function after Page Load
        AddReadMore();
    });
    </script>
```

```css
     <style>
    .addReadMore.showlesscontent .SecSec,
    .addReadMore.showlesscontent .readLess {
        display: none;
    }

    .addReadMore.showmorecontent .readMore {
        display: none;
    }

    .addReadMore .readMore,
    .addReadMore .readLess {
        margin-left: 2px;
        color: #242424;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .addReadMore .readMore span,
    .addReadMore .readLess span {text-decoration:underline;}

    .addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .SecSec,
    .addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .readLess {
        display: block;
    }
/*  span.cless {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }*/
    </style>
```

```html
<div class="addReadMore showlesscontent">A strong, masculine fragrance, Dylan Blue encapsulates the sensual scents of the Mediterranean. The fragrance bold ambrox notes, refreshed with hints of bergamot and grapefruit. The earthy and citrusy olfactory notes are enveloped with black pepper, papyrus wood and incense, along with mineral musk, tonka beans and saffron. The bold perfume is stored in a blue, geometric bottle enriched with gold tone accents, evoking the Mediterranean Sea and sand.</div>
```

Comment: Where is the problem guys?